# In Django Rest Framework, how can I view paginated data with TemplateHTMLRenderer?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and I'm trying to convert from the API view to a TemplateHTMLResponse using the [doc example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/).  I was able to complete most of it and got the template loaded and passing all the data, however documentation on the HTML side of the process is scarce.

The problem I am having is the results not being paginated. I am able to access and iterate over all the data, but I need the pagination for organization.

views.py.

```
class BoxViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Uploadobject.objects.all().exclude(verified=False)
    serializer_class = BoxSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                            IsBox)

    #renderer_classes = (renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer)
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Uploadobject.objects.all().exclude(verified=False)


        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, data=request.data)

            if serializer.is_valid():

                serdata = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
                data= {'objects': queryset,
                    'serializers': serializer}
                return Response(data, template_name='restframework/objectlist.html')
```

objectlist.html

```
{% if serializers %}  
{{ serializers }}
{% endif %}

  {% if objects %}
    {% for object in objects %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ object.Title }}</li>
            <li>{{ object.Category }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}

    {% else %}
        <p>No objects.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

I have tried many things including the ListModelMixin and creating a custom pagination script as recommended by the [pagination docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/), but nothing seems to pass through. I read that there is way to paginate from Django, but I think keeping all the pagination in Django Rest Framework will be simpler. From what I can tell I have the correct backend data and the HTML  just needs to be corrected. So to sum it up, what is the easiest way to display all my model data in a paginated setup on my template page?

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because even though you paginated the queryset using DRF methods, you are still sending the response with the original queryset.

Something like this should work:

```
renderer_classes = (renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer, )

def list(self, request):
    queryset = Uploadobject.objects.all().exclude(verified=False)
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, data=request.data)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    data= {'objects': queryset, 'serializers': serializer}
    return Response(data, template_name='restframework/objectlist.html')
```

Comment: This is how the docs mention it, and doens't work for me. First I get the error that I need to add if `serializer.is_valid():`, which is simple enough to add. I get the error that  `Returned a template response with no 'template_name' attribute set on either the view or response`. This doesn't return a Response object, so I am also unable to pass the HTML parameters.  Can I access the paginated return from an HTML page?

Comment: @RknRobin  Did you find answer for your question?

Comment: @Patrick Nope. I have since abandoned my lofty Django dreams.